# How do you break a line of text within InDesign scripts?

Tags: break, adobe-indesign, extendscript

So I'm new to InDesign CC scripting, but I really just need a very simple solution, or at least I hope that it's a simple solution. I have a script for adding a watermark to a document for export, however i'd like it to be on two lines and take up more space on the page rather than just one line. Below is the script I'm using:

```js
var myDoc = app.activeDocument,
  myPdfExportPreset = "[High Quality Print]",
  myPdfFile = File(myDoc.fullName.fsName.replace(/.indd$/i, "") + ".pdf");

app.scriptPreferences.measurementUnit = MeasurementUnits.INCHES

var docHeight = myDoc.documentPreferences.pageHeight
var docWidth = myDoc.documentPreferences.pageWidth

with(myDoc.watermarkPreferences)
{
  watermarkVisibility = true;
  watermarkDoPrint = true;
  watermarkDrawInBack = false;
  watermarkText = "I would like the code to split between the word split and between";
  watermarkFontFamily = "Helvetica";
  watermarkFontStyle = "Bold";
  watermarkFontPointSize = Math.round(docWidth * 7);
  watermarkFontColor = [0, 0, 0];
  watermarkOpacity = 15;
  watermarkRotation = -25;
  watermarkHorizontalPosition = WatermarkHorizontalPositionEnum.watermarkHCenter;
  watermarkHorizontalOffset = 0;
  watermarkVerticalPosition = WatermarkVerticalPositionEnum.watermarkVCenter;
  watermarkVerticalOffset = 0;
}
```

If anyone has an idea on how to insert a line break, I'm not sure if it's like html where you can just `<br>` and be done with it, but that's kind of what I'm looking for, if that makes sense. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Admittedly I have never used the watermark feature, but you should be able to insert a break within your text by inserting either `\r` or `\n` (including the backslash). Not sure which one will work, probably both. Give it a try.

Comment: ^^^^^ If that doesn't work, try `^p` or `^n`